# Elastic Search sort preprocessing

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have an index in ES that has, in addition to other fields, revenue_amount and revenue_currency fields. The revenue is stored in different currencies. At run time, all currencies are converted to USD and rendered.

Now, I would like to support sorting on the revenue_amount field. The problem is ES sorts results in terms of revenue prior to converting to USD, and so a revenue returned at the top might not be the highest revenue after converting to USD.

I was wondering, if its possible that before sorting, ES calls a user-defined function that changes a field value, and then apply sort afterwards? Something like this:

> revenue_converted = convertToUSD(revenue)

And so the sorting will be applied to revenue_converted, rather than revenue.

I know I can convert the currencies at index time, but that will require refreshing the index every time the rates are updated, and so I would like to avoid it, if possible.

Comment: if you have scripting enabled in elasticsearch you can use [script based sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two ways of achieving this: one is by using [script-based sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting) as keety mentioned:

```
{
    "query" : {
        ....                                    <--- your query goes here
    },
    "sort" : {
        "_script" : {
            "script" : "doc.revenue_amount.value * usd_conversion_rate",
            "type" : "number",
            "params" : {
                "usd_conversion_rate" : 0.4273  <--- the conversion rate to USD
            },
            "order" : "desc"
        }
    }
}
```

The `usd_conversion_rate` factor is the conversion rate to USD. So for instance, if 1 USD is worth 2.34 units of another currency, the `usd_conversion_rate` factor would be `1 / 2.34` (or `0.4273`). When multiplied with `revenue_amount` it'll give you the amount in the USD reference currency.

Script-based sorting is not very performant, though, and the recommendation is to use a `function_score` so results can be sorted by score instead. That leads us to the second way of achieving what you need and it goes like this. One way is by using a [`script_score`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-script-score) function, but that involves scripting again.

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {},
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": "doc.revenue_amount.value * usd_conversion_rate",
            "boost_mode": "replace",
            "params": {
              "usd_conversion_rate": 0.4273
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Since our above script was very simple (i.e. multiply a field by some factor), the simplest way would involve using [`field_value_factor`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor) and it goes like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        ...                              <--- your query goes here
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "revenue_amount",
            "boost_mode": "replace",
            "factor": 0.4273             <--- insert the conversion rate here
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

According to your latest comment, it seems that the right option for you is to use `script_score` after all. The idea here would be to input all your currency rates available in your lookup table as parameters of your `script_score` script and then use the proper one according to the value of the `revenue_currency` field.

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {},
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": "doc.revenue_amount.value * (doc.revenue_currency.value == 'EUR' ? EUR : (doc.revenue_currency.value == 'AUD' ? AUD : 1))",
            "boost_mode": "replace",
            "params": {
              "EUR": 0.4945,
              "AUD": 0.5623
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case, factor is not static, rather it depends on the underlying revenue_currency field stored in ES. How can I call my function and pass it corresponding revenue_currency field? i.e "factor": conversionRate(doc.revenue_currency.value)

Comment: Can you show a sample value for your `revenue_currency` field, please? I was under the impression that you didn't want to store the currency rates in your docs in order to not have to reindex them when rates change (which makes sense)

Comment: Lets say, I have revenue stored in three different currencies, usd, euro and aud. At run time, I convert all of them into usd. I have a lookup table which tells me the conversion rate from usd to euro and aud. So before I can convert any revenue field, I need to check the corresponding revenue_currency field to find out the conversion rate. And yes, the currency rates are not indexed, but the currency codes are indexed.