# Elasticsearch displaying product prices with vat calculations

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch, solr, lucene

**Scope**:

I would like to use Elasticsearch services for an ecommerce search engine.

**Situation**:

I found a limitation, I checked search engine based on Lucene like style services (eg:Algolia, Solr & Elasticsearch)) and we have to update a JSON directly to the indices and retrieve that information directly to the frontend.

**Research**:

If you support a dozen of countries, you can add the price for each country to your records, and then select which one to display in your front-end once the whole record is retrieved.

For example, you would have within your records {"price_FR": "15€", "price_US": "15$", ...}, and choose in your front-end logic which price to display depending on the country of your customer.

**My question**:

if an ecommerce platform wants to display product prices with modifications based on:
- VAT for a country.
- any price modification based on a particular customer.

how do we have to manage the index or response technically to perform that operation in a manner more typical of sql procedures? mainly to replicate sql functionalities of price calculations. I mean options like:

1. in sql you have the price, and then you perform calculations
   like: if country x then price * vat_country. = new price.

Or a different approach where:

2. application avoid indexing the price information in elasticsearch and
   retrieve the information from elasticsearch but including the price
   from the mysql registry.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Ideas from this answer could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32058673/elastic-search-sort-preprocessing/32063301#32063301 then based on that you could use [`script_fields`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html) to compute the price with VAT dynamically for the retrieved document.

Comment: @Val thank you, reading the post right now.