# Elasticsearch How to use a compound query and sorting?

Tags: elasticsearch

**I have two separate indexes -**
1. products
2. currency_rates

**documents in the product index, have the following details -**

```
{
       "prod_id" : 1,
       "currency" : "USD",
       "price" : 1
}
```

**documents in the currency_rates index, have the following details -**

```
{
      "id" : 1,
      "USD" : 1,
      "SGD" : 0.72,
      "MYR" : 0.24,
      "INR" : 0.014,
      "EUR" : 1.12
}
```

I wish to achieve sorting on **products index's price field**,
but because **every document in the product index might have different currencies**,
I need to first convert all the currencies into USD,
And the carryout sorting on the converted resultset.

Eg.-
**products -**

```
[{
    "prod_id": 1,
    "currency": "USD",
    "price": 1

}, {
    "prod_id": 2,
    "currency": "INR",
    "price": 60

}]
```

**currency_rates -**

```
{
    "USD": 1,
    "SGD": 0.72,
    "MYR": 0.24,
    "INR": 0.014,
    "EUR": 1.12
}
```

**Following are my creation queries -**

```
GET curency_rates/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}

PUT /curency_rates/_doc/1
{
  "id":1,
  "USD" : 1,
  "SGD" : 0.72,
  "MYR" : 0.24,
  "INR" : 0.014,
  "EUR" : 1.12
}


PUT /products/_doc/1?pretty
{
    "prod_id":1,
    "currency": "USD",
    "price": 1
}
PUT /products/_doc/2?pretty
{
    "prod_id":2,
    "currency": "INR",
    "price": 60
}

GET products/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Found that the following is a very similar use-case to mine,
But I couldn't understand how the are fetching conversion factor from another index at run time and, then using it in their compound query -
[Elastic Search sort preprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32058673/elastic-search-sort-preprocessing/32063301)

I've come up with the following query,
Based on the answer in the above link I'm referring -

```
GET products/_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "functions": [{
                "script_score": {
                    "script": {
                        "params": {
                            "USD": 1,
                            "SGD": 0.72,
                            "MYR": 0.24,
                            "INR": 0.014,
                            "EUR": 1.12
                        },
                        "source": "doc['price'].value * params.EUR"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

**But I'm getting the wrong result -**

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 4,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 67.2,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 67.2,
        "_source" : {
          "prod_id" : 2,
          "currency" : "INR",
          "price" : 60
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 2.24,
        "_source" : {
          "prod_id" : 3,
          "currency" : "EUR",
          "price" : 2
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.12,
        "_source" : {
          "prod_id" : 1,
          "currency" : "USD",
          "price" : 1
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "5",
        "_score" : 1.12,
        "_source" : {
          "prod_id" : 5,
          "currency" : "MYR",
          "price" : 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**References -**
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-script-score
https://qbox.io/blog/scoring-using-elasticsearch-scripts-part1

**Query -**
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Read this [example](https://qbox.io/blog/scoring-using-elasticsearch-scripts-part1). They have the "boost_mode" and "functions" fields at the same level.

Try:

```
 "functions": [ 
     { 
         "script_score": { 
             "script": MathHere, 
             "params": { 
                 ... 
             } 
         } 
     }
 ], 
 "boost_mode": "replace"
```

Hope this is helpful! :D

Comment: I updated the question with the changes, still getting a wrongly sorted result

Comment: How about using doc['price'].value & doc['currency'].value in "source"?

Comment: Works with brackets but still returning the wrong result, I guess it's not able to do the calculation

Comment: Delete the boost mode. If you use "replace", the query will use the script_score. Meaning that the "match_all" is not being computed"

Comment: I removed "boost_mode": "replace" from the query and ran it, still same result :/

Comment: Yes. If not included, it has "multiply" in boost_mode as default.

Comment: How about only use "source": "doc['price'].value * params.doc['currency'].value instead of your nested if's?

Comment: Also try to use params.doc['currency'] without the .value thing.

Comment: Tried - "source": "doc['price'].value * params['EUR']", same result, gave error on "source": "doc['price'].value * params.doc['currency'].value"

Comment: Also, in the example I first shared with you, they don't use "params." (which I find not that clear...), they only call the param by its name

Comment: Try only to use "params.EUR" without brackets so all of them should multiply by EUR

Comment: params.EUR worked, it's calculating the _score now, but couldn't work with the ternary operator for multiple currencies cases, I've updated the query and response in question

Comment: What's the error you're getting while running the "params.doc['currency'] thing? Does it happen if you also add .value at the end?

Comment: I'm getting a script_exception for "source": "doc['price'].value * params.['currency'].value", I think that's because what I need is params value of doc['currency']

Comment: So params.doc['currency'].value & params.doc['currency']  show the same error message?

Comment: "source": "doc['price'].value * params.doc['currency']" gives -> script_exception
updated question

Comment: This works -> `"source": "doc['price'].value * (doc['currency'].value == 'EUR' ? params.doc['currency'] : 1000)"` with wrong response but this doesn't -> `"source": "doc['price'].value * params.doc['currency']"`

Comment: Painless makes everything painful lol. Try doc ['price'].value * doc ['currency'] (you know, with and without the .value). Here, they don't use "params." at all (like in the example which I said wasn't clear): https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html#prefer-params

Comment: Under that logic, doc['price'].value * EUR should also work without the "params." Thing

Comment: this worked - `"source": "doc['price'].value * params[doc['currency.keyword'].value]"`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197932/discussion-on-answer-by-kevin-quinzel-elasticsearch-how-to-use-a-compound-query).