# Elasticsearch currency conversion and search handling?

Tags: elasticsearch, currency

**Step 1**

I have job search candidates whow enters their salary in any of the 10 predefined currency. In the background I convert the salary in to each possible
currency based on  predefined conversion rate for each currency.This data is stored in Elasticsearch.

**Step 2**

Now any recruiter(rec) can search the candidate in any of the 10 currency. Say rec searches for candidates with more than 10000 australian dollar salary,
it will look for the values already converted in step 1

**Problem :** As conversion rate keep on changing every day, results returned may not be accurate.

**Solution :** One solution I can think of is to re index the data after every x days. But that is not the real time and ideal solution for two reasons. 
Reason 1: Till data is not index , it won't be correct results. I am not looking for real time but looking forward to take it closer as much as it can be.
Reason 2 : Time taken to re index the complete data is in days which may impact my current traffic.

**Is there any better solution** elastic provides off the shelf as it is very common use case.

Comment: Another way is to make it dynamic and search with a variable exchange rate. See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32063301/4604579

Comment: Thanks. Looks close but what if recruiter has to search based on given salary range. For example he has to search for candidates b/w 5000 to 1000 American dollar. Now candidate profiles has come into system over last few months where each each candidate had some salary which is converted to another possible salaries based on that day conversion rate. Looks like here I have get each candidate document and his original currency. Then convert each candidate salary to recruiter selecetd currency based on that day ceonversion rate. Is it ?

Comment: Also then i won't be able to use inverted index as I need to look up each document. Isn't it ?

Comment: @Val can you please help here ?